# multiple GoogleService-Info support

Tags: ios, firebase

I registered my Dev and Prod schemes as different apps in Firebase. I want them to be separate, Each has unique bundle ID. I am using #if dev to identify if it is dev or prod scheme. How can I initialize firebase with a dedicated plist for for that scheme?

Answer (score 5):

Just use [FIRApp configureWithOptions:]

```
NSString *firebasePlist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GoogleService-Info" ofType:@"plist"];

#if STAGING
    firebasePlist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GoogleService-Info-DEV" ofType:@"plist"];
#endif

FIROptions *options = [[FIROptions alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:firebasePlist];
[FIRApp configureWithOptions:options];
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
var firebasePlist: String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info", ofType: "plist")
if development == true{
firebasePlist = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info-DEV", ofType: "plist")
}
var options = FIROptions(contentsOfFile: firebasePlist)
FIRApp.configure(with: options)
```

but you'll have to have a variable called development with the value of true when you want to use the DEV GoogleService plist and the value of false is you want to use the regular GoogleService plist

Comment: Oh, that's my answer just bellow