# Firebase Development and Production Setup

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I was wondering if anyone knew of a good way for handling a Development and Production environment type setup when it comes to using Firebase on iOS? I don't want to duplicate Xcode projects and would rather just have one. Is there something that can be done in the Google plist config file? Really just wondering if anyone could offer some insight into how they avoid touching their production Firebase account when developing further.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728809/multiple-googleservice-info-support

Comment: Thats exactly what I was searching for.  Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen