# Xcode Swift Firebase How to create a second instance of FIRAuth

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

Anyone know how I can create a second instance of FIRAuth in Swift? You see, these days you cannot create a new user programatically. Then you will be signed in as the new user that you create. Like this:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: txtUsername.text!, password: txtPassword.text!, completion: {
        user, error in
        //your stuff
    })
```

The workaround is to create a second instance of FIRAuth and that actually creates the new users without you being signed out.

```
SecondFIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: txtUsername.text!, password: txtPassword.text!, completion: {
        user, error in
        //your stuff
    })
```

It would be great to have some code advice how I can manage this.

Comment: how about declaring this `var SecondFIRAuth = FIRAuth()` globally ?

Comment: You'll need to create a second `FIRApp` and then [`FIRAuth.authWithApp()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/interface_f_i_r_auth.html#ae1ef631c29aac73a5a2f1ab417ebda71). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38728809/multiple-googleservice-info-support

Answer (score 0):

After creating a user, I think you don't need to createUser again.

You can auth the existing user something like,

```
BASE_REF.authUser(email, password: password, withCompletionBlock: { (error, authData) -> Void in
                if (error == nil) {

                 // Auth success, 
                 // Do your stuff here

                } else {
                    print(error)
                }
            })
```

where BASE_REF is my firebase global reference as suggested by Dravidian in comment